# operators overloading, odd seg fault, classes, c++

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault, operator-overloading

I was given an exercise on overloading operators by my tutor. He gave me the int main() function which cannot be changed. I was supposed to write the functions etc so that the code would work. Unfortunately I have a seg fault. I've noticed that if the

```
 TSeries series4=series1(2,4);
 cout << "Series4: " << series4 << endl;
```

lines are commented it's more or less working. I would be very grateful for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
class TSeries {
public:
    TSeries()
    {
        _size = 0;
        _capacity = 0;
        _tab = NULL;
    }


    TSeries(float *tab, const int size)
    {
        _tab = new float[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) _tab[i] = tab[i];
        _size = size;
        _capacity = 0;
    }

    ~TSeries() { delete[] _tab; }

    TSeries & operator+=(float value) { return insert(value); }
    TSeries & operator,(float value) { return insert(value); }
    TSeries & operator+(const TSeries & s)
    {
        //  if(this->_size != s._size) std::cout<<"Size doesn't match!"<<std::endl;
        /*else
        {
        std::cout<<"whee";
        for(int i; i<this->_size;i++)
        {
        //this->_tab[i] += s._tab[i];
        std::cout<<"nothing";
        }
        return *this;
        }*/
        //std::cout<<"sth";
    }

    TSeries & operator()(int position1, int position2)
    {
        // return *this;
    }

    TSeries & insert(float k)
    {
        if (_size >= _capacity) Enlarge();
        _tab[_size++] = k;
        return *this;
    }
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const TSeries & s);


private:
    int _size, _capacity;
    float *_tab, *_itr;
    static int _nr;

    void Enlarge()
    {
        _capacity = 2 * _capacity + 1;
        float *tmp = new float[_capacity];

        for (int i = 0; i < _size; ++i)
        {
            tmp[i] = _tab[i];
        }
        delete[] _tab;
        _tab = tmp;
    }
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const TSeries & s)
{
    int przedostatni = s._size - 1;
    out << "(";
    for (int i = 0; i < s._size; i++)
    {
        out << (int)s._tab[i];
        if (i != przedostatni)
            out << ",";
    }
    out << ")" << std::endl;
}

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    TSeries series1;
    series1 += 1., 2., 4., 2.;
    cout << "Series1: " << series1 << endl;

    const int size = 7;
    float tab[size] = { 3.,3.,3.,4.,5.,1.,0. };
    const TSeries series2(tab, size);
    cout << "Series2: " << series2 << endl << endl;


    TSeries series3 = series1 + series2;
    cout << "Series3: " << series3 << endl << endl;

    series1 += 1., 0., 3.;
    series3 = series1 + series2;
    cout << "           " << series1 << endl;
    cout << "          +" << series2 << endl;
    cout << "        ---------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Series3:   " << series3 << endl << endl;

    TSeries series4 = series1(2, 4);
    cout << "Series4: " << series4 << endl;

    return 0;
}

/* output required:
Series1: (1,2,4,2)
Series2: (3,3,3,4,5,1,0)

Size doesn't match!
Series3: ()

(1,2,4,2,1,0,3)
+(3,3,3,4,5,1,0)
---------------------
Series3:   (4,5,7,6,6,1,3)

Series4: (4,2)
*/
```

Comment: The expression `series1 += 1.,2.,4.,2.` does not do what you expect it, unless you expect it to be the same as `series1 += 2.`. Read about [the comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

Comment: I wanted it to work like multiple insert function, meaning that firstly, there is series1 +=1 then seires1 += 2 ect.

Comment: Also, you should really read about [the rules of three, five and zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Good ol' comma operator: it evaluates the first expression, discards it, evaluates the second expression and returns that. Such a nice thing!

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: It should be noted that the comma operator is actually overloaded here, and it does appear to work as intended.

Answer (score 3):

1. `std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const TSeries & s)` doesn't return anything. Please add a `return out` at the end of the function
2. `operator()` and `operator+` should both end with `return *this`
3. As *Devolus* already pointed out: You don't have a copy constructor and no `operator=(const TSeries&)` defined
4. You can use `memcpy` to copy the arrays faster.#
5. The `i` in the for-loop in `operator+(const TSeries&)` isn't initialized.
6. Your `operator(int, int)` does currently alter the original object. This doesn't seem right.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
class TSeries {
public:
    TSeries()
    {
        _size = 0;
        _capacity = 0;

        _tab = NULL;
    }


    TSeries(float *tab, const int size)
    {
        _size = size;
        _capacity = 0;

        _tab = new float[size];
        memcpy(_tab, tab, _size*sizeof(float));
    }

    TSeries(const TSeries& other)
    {
        _size = other._size;
        _capacity = other._capacity;

        _tab = new float[_size];
        memcpy(_tab, other._tab, _size*sizeof(float));
    }

    ~TSeries() 
    { 
        delete[] _tab;
    }

    TSeries & operator+=(float value) { return insert(value); }
    TSeries & operator,(float value) { return insert(value); }
    TSeries & operator+(const TSeries & other)
    {
        if (this->_size != other._size)
        {
            std::cout << "Size doesn't match!" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            //std::cout << "whee";
            for (int i = 0; i < this->_size; i++)
            {
                _tab[i] += other._tab[i];
                //std::cout << "nothing";
            }
        }
        //std::cout<<"sth";
        return *this;
    }

    TSeries& operator=(const TSeries& other)
    {
        _size = other._size;
        _capacity = other._capacity;
        //Create tmp in case of self-assignment
        float *tmp = new float[_capacity];
        memcpy(tmp, other._tab, _size*sizeof(float));
        delete[] _tab;
        _tab = tmp;
        return *this;
    }

    TSeries operator()(int position1, int position2)
    {
        //TODO: Range-Check
        return TSeries(_tab + position1, position2 - position1);
    }

    TSeries & insert(float k)
    {
        if (_size >= _capacity) Enlarge();
        _tab[_size++] = k;
        return *this;
    }
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const TSeries & s);


private:
    int _size, _capacity;
    float *_tab, *_itr;
    static int _nr;

    void Enlarge()
    {
        _capacity = 2 * _capacity + 1;
        float *tmp = new float[_capacity];
        memcpy(tmp, _tab, _size*sizeof(float));
        delete[] _tab;
        _tab = tmp;
    }
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const TSeries & s)
{
    int przedostatni = s._size - 1;
    out << "(";
    for (int i = 0; i < s._size; i++)
    {
        out << (int)s._tab[i];
        if (i != przedostatni)
            out << ",";
    }
    out << ")" << std::endl;
    return out;
}

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    TSeries series1;
    series1 += 1., 2., 4., 2.;
    cout << "Series1: " << series1 << endl;

    const int size = 7;
    float tab[size] = { 3.,3.,3.,4.,5.,1.,0. };
    const TSeries series2(tab, size);
    cout << "Series2: " << series2 << endl << endl;


    TSeries series3 = series1 + series2;
    cout << "Series3: " << series3 << endl << endl;

    series1 += 1., 0., 3.;
    series3 = series1 + series2;
    cout << "           " << series1 << endl;
    cout << "          +" << series2 << endl;
    cout << "        ---------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Series3:   " << series3 << endl << endl;

    TSeries series4 = series1(2, 4);
    cout << "Series4: " << series4 << endl;

    return 0;
}

/* output required:
Series1: (1,2,4,2)
Series2: (3,3,3,4,5,1,0)

Size doesn't match!
Series3: ()

(1,2,4,2,1,0,3)
+(3,3,3,4,5,1,0)
---------------------
Series3:   (4,5,7,6,6,1,3)

Series4: (4,2)
*/
```

**Output**

```
Series1: (1,2,4,2)

Series2: (3,3,3,4,5,1,0)


Size doesn't match!
Series3: (1,2,4,2)


           (4,5,7,6,6,1,3)

          +(3,3,3,4,5,1,0)

        ---------------------
Series3:   (4,5,7,6,6,1,3)


Series4: (7,6)
```

**UPDATE:**

Your `operator+(const TSeries &)` should look somewhat like this:

```
TSeries operator+(const TSeries & other)
{
    if (this->_size != other._size)
    {
        std::cout << "Size doesn't match!" << std::endl;
        return TSeries(); //Return empty object
    }
    TSeries tmp(*this); //Create copy
    for (int i = 0; i < tmp._size; i++)
    {
        tmp._tab[i] += other._tab[i];
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

And your `operator()(int, int)` like this:

```
TSeries operator()(int position1, int position2)
{
    if (position1 < 0) position1 = 0;
    else if (position1 >= _size) position1 = _size - 1;

    if (position2 < position1) position2 = position1;
    else if (position2 >= _size) position2 = _size - 1;

    return TSeries(_tab + position1, position2 - position1);
}
```

Maybe you want to throw exceptions in the error cases?

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question: what do you mean by:  //TODO: Range-Check?

Comment: @annakowalska In general I just fixed the most obvious stuff. For the range check case: Think about having a series with 1 element, but you want to extract the range 2 to 20. This will lead to a crash in the solution as `_tmp` is accessed out of the bounds. The correct way would be to check if the range is valid (e.g. `from >= 0 and from <_size and to >= from and to < size`) and handle invalid values accordingly.